# How to set interval 1 by 1 in each loop of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, setinterval

```
var J_lis = $(".display");        
// loop thought each element
J_lis.each(function(g){
  g = self.setInterval(function () {
  alert("this");
  }, 1000);
})
```

my intention is to set a loop through each element and set a interval to each. so the 1st element go and 2nd element will start after 1000 and so on. but this code wont go 1 by 1 , it will go a quick loop of 4 time and then stop and go 4 times again.

i want it go though each by each and each wait 1000.

```
for (var f=0; f < J_lis.length; f++){
  f = self.setInterval(function () {
    // code
  }, 1000);
}
```

this code work just fine like i wanted , but i wanted to set in on jquery each , is there a way of doing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should increase delay of interval in loop. Set interval delay relevant to loop index. For example like `(index + 1) * 1000`

```js
$(".display").each(function(i,ele){
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log($(ele).text());
  }, (i+1)*1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display">Element 1</div>
<div class="display">Element 2</div>
<div class="display">Element 3</div>
<div class="display">Element 4</div>
<div class="display">Element 5</div>
```

Comment: @deecheok `setTimeout()` run once but `setInterval()` run unlimited and need to `clearInterval` to stoping it.